# Bootstrap4: Why is the other row cell left-justified, and not centered despite mx-auto?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to create a responsive header in Bootstrap4. The intent was to create a left-justified LOGO (text) and right-justified menu when the viewport is large, then when shrunk to "small" viewport, both become centered.

This is what I have so far:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-white no-gutters py-0 border-bottom">
        <div class="nav col-sm-6 bg-secondary">
            <DIV class="mx-auto">
              <a class="navbar-brand text-light p-2 h3" href="#">LOGO</a>
            </DIV>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <ul class="nav mx-auto float-sm-right text-dark bg-success">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link p-2" href="#">Menu1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link p-2" href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link p-2" href="#">Menu3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

NOTE: Please disregard the hideous backgrounds, I was using them to debug my grid's responsiveness and which element to stick a utility on.

Everything looks right at the wide viewport. But as I shrink the width, the LOGO is centered, but the menu jumped to LEFT justified. I've tried mx-auto in the line above it (in the DIV) but no change in behavior was observed.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use d-flex justify-content-center classes to make the menu items center align.**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-white no-gutters py-0 border-bottom">
        <div class="nav col-sm-6 bg-secondary">
            <div class="mx-auto">
              <a class="navbar-brand text-light p-2 h3" href="#">LOGO</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
           <ul class="nav mx-auto d-flex justify-content-center float-sm-right text-dark bg-success">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link p-2" href="#">Menu1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link p-2" href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link p-2" href="#">Menu3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Great, it works. Now the dumb question... WHY is that needed? I'm guessing I didn't expand the "menu" section into a flexbox (d-flex) that takes up 100% of allowed width? I'll accept your answer, of course.

Comment: Menu section is a flexbox that flows right due to flow-sm-right. d-flex turns container into a flex-box (takes up all horizontal space available) when size=sm then justify-content-center actually centers the content WITHIN the flexbox.